# Stripe integration with Django rest and Angular/Cli

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, stripe-payments, angular-cli, webhooks

I want to create a stripe payment integration using Django Rest Framework as backend and Angular/Cli as frontend. And also I want to confirm the payment using stripe webhooks. I could not able to find Angular documentation just for the only frontend. And also the Stripe docs are generally has written for flask and not for the rest framework. Any help will be appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Welcome to SO, please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 2):

I've found a library and some newer docs that I think will solve your issues: https://richnologies.gitbook.io/ngx-stripe/core-concepts/checkout

Using the ngx-stripe library as a wrapper, you can setup the publishable key on your front end. The library then offers a StripeService.

If you setup some custom endpoints on your backend to handle the dirty work (accept payments, create customers, etc), you can have then have the StripeService listen for the response and react accordingly (create a checkout session, display payment successful message, etc.)

Comment: I am especially looking for something that I can use Django as the backend to send requests and check stripe webhook. The solution that you shared is using Angular with only front-end integration. Thank you anyway, it is the only answer :)